# SQL Server Stored Procedure Get a value from a row just inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I'm new to writing stored procedures and I'm trying to create a one that will be used to determine if a paypal transaction id exists in the database and if not add a customer to the database using the procedure parameters then return either the new customer's ID or -1 to indicate the transaction was already processed before.

Here is what I have for the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addCustomerIfNotExist] @txn_id varchar(max), @fName nvarchar(255), @lastName nvarchar(255), @e_mail nvarchar(255), @password nvarchar(100), @customerId int OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN
    -- if the transaction id has not already been processed
    if (select count(txn_id) from paypal_txns WHERE txn_id=@txn_id) = 0
        BEGIN
            --add txn id to the paypal_txns table
            INSERT INTO paypal_txns VALUES(@txn_id)
            --if the email address not is already in the database
            IF (select count(email) from customers where email = @e_mail) = 0
                BEGIN
                    --generate a new customer account 
                    INSERT INTO customers (pcCust_AgreeTerms,pcCust_Guest,pcCust_Residential,pcCust_AllowReviewEmails,name,lastname,email,password) VALUES(0,0,1,1,@fName,@lastName,@e_mail,@password)
                END
            --get the customer id 
            select @customerId = idcustomer from customers where email = @e_mail
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @customerId = -1
        END
    END
GO
```

I'm using a simple ASP page to test the results of this procedure.  Here is the bulk of my code for my ASP page:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   Set cmd.ActiveConnection = paypalIpnDbCon
   cmd.CommandText = "addCustomerIfNotExist"
   cmd.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("txn_id", 200, 1,-1,"abcdefg") 

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fName", 202, 1,-1,"John") 

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("lastName", 202, 1,-1,"Doe") 

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("e_mail", 202, 1,-1,"johndoe@fake.com") 

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("password", 202, 1,-1,randomPassword) 

   cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("customerId", 3, 2) 

   Set rs = cmd.Execute

   custId = cmd.Parameters("customerId")
   response.write("<br>Customer ID = " & custId & "<br>")
```

When I run the ASP page without having the transaction ID (abcdefg) in the paypal_txns table it will display "Customer ID = " as if the ID is empty, null, or otherwise does not exist.  The second time I run the ASP page it displays "Customer ID = -1" because the transaction ID is in the table now.

I've also tried tweaking the code a bit to see if I can get a valid customer ID back and I can get a value other than -1 if I change the logic around but it still only shows up after I run the ASP a second time.

I'm thinking there must be something I'm overlooking in my stored procedure code... any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i didn't work much with classic asp
but instead of taking value in output parameter, if you can use in recordset object.

```
if (select count(txn_id) from paypal_txns WHERE txn_id=@txn_id) = 0
    BEGIN
        --add txn id to the paypal_txns table
        INSERT INTO paypal_txns VALUES(@txn_id)
        --if the email address not is already in the database
        IF (select count(email) from customers where email = @e_mail) = 0
            BEGIN
                --generate a new customer account 
                INSERT INTO customers (pcCust_AgreeTerms,pcCust_Guest,pcCust_Residential,pcCust_AllowReviewEmails,name,lastname,email,password) VALUES(0,0,1,1,@fName,@lastName,@e_mail,@password)
            END
        --get the customer id 
        select @customerId = idcustomer from customers where email = @e_mail
        select @customerId as custid
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @customerId = -1
        select @customerId as custid
    END
END
```

You can read the custid using

recordset.fields("custid")

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get "ADODB.recordset error '800a0cc1' Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal." but this only happens the first time I run the stored procedure.  On the second run I get the expected value of -1

Comment: i tried to simulate your problem and i found out that when we try to fill recordset with new transactionid no value returns in recordset.
thats why its is giving error.
same is happening to me also.
i think this something has to do with recordset.because stored procedure is returning value in both case.
thats all i know....
Hope you can find some alternative to this

Comment: The only workaround that comes to mind is to separate the logic so that the customer data is inserted first then retrieved in a separate query or procedure call.  I was hoping to insert and retrieve the data in the same procedure call but maybe it's just simpler to split it up.

Comment: well if you can consult any asp expert regarding recordset because SP is working correctly and is giving proper result.you can even debug the SP,you'll get expected result. 
rest i would go with this alternative.
cheers!!!!